# How to use a Velocity variable in an AWS API Gateway Response template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, velocity

I'm unable to use a variable in an API Gateway Response

Here's a **simplified** example of a Response template I use to test variable usage

```
#set( $message= "message" )
{$message:$context.error.messageString}
```

This is the response that I expect

```
{
  message : "Unauthorized"
}
```

This is the actual response:

```
#set( = "message" )
{
    : "Unauthorized"
}
```

This is similar to the [Hello Velocity World!](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html#hello-velocity-world) example as described in the [Apache Velocity Engine - User Guide](https://velocity.apache.org/engine/1.7/user-guide.html)

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: The template looks correct and translates to `{message:Unauthorized}` when I tested using a [velocity tester](https://github.com/devatherock/velocity-template-tester) that I wrote. You can find the test curl command [here](https://gist.github.com/devatherock/d3e54f75b45636d0661599333cc67396)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue.
I needed to perform logic to map my responses correctly.
Ended up stumbling on this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-swagger-extensions-gateway-responses.responseTemplates.html which flat out says "we don't parse VTL in gateway responses".

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
{"message":$context.error.messageString}
```

Would give you the results you wanted.